# From Hong Kong to Macau: Stay over night or do the boat trip every morning?

Tags: hong-kong, macau

I am planning to visit Macau when I am in Hong Kong for 2 days.

I already have accommodation in HK, booked the entire week of cheap hostels, and I was wondering if it's worth to spend a bit more to stay overnight in Macau or do the boat trip "dance" back and forth every day?

The question is not only about the costs alone, but what would I be missing from the city when returning back to HK every night.

Comment: How close is your hostel to the ferry terminal? I'd have thought that would make a big difference as to how practical it is!

Comment: The ferry only takes 60 minutes, however when you take travel and immigration into account on both sides then I would say you are looking at least 4 hours travel each day.

Comment: Also note that apart from Casinos, there isn't a great deal of nightlife in Macau (compared to Hong Kong). Even the famous shows (e.g. at the Venetian) will end before the last ferries back to Hong Kong.

Answer (score 2):

If you're travelling on a budget - which I assume you are because you're staying in hostels - then the key thing would be to find a place to spend the night in Macau. The only hostel that I know of in Macau was [Augusters Lodge](http://www.augusters.de/) (they weren't on Hostelworld) but as far as I know they shut down. So the only option for "cheap" accommodation that's left is [Couchsurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org).

The other option for exploring the nightlife of Macau is to crash and catch some sleep in a casino. The big ones like City of Dreams or the Venetian don't really care. The ferry from Hong Kong to Macau doesn't take too long though, so if you feel tired then you can easily head back to your Hong Kong hostel to get sleep.

Comment: Hi, could you explain how to "catch some sleep" in a casino? I have never done that and I am interested. :D thanks

Comment: Um, just fall asleep at a slot machine. They don't really care. Obviously there are rooms you can hire too but it's really expensive.